# when click on button how to call one heritage human service to another heritage human service in BPM 8.5.5

Tags: business-process-management, new-window, ibm-bpm

I created two heritage human services HS1 and HS2. In HS1 have one button using that button when click on i want to show HS2 first. if i show the HS2 the next i want to show HS2 in new window why because of i am easily compare the things in both HS1 and HS2.

HS1--Duplicate Case list Human Service

HS2--Duplicate case details Human Service

HS1 having the duplicate case details list when click on any list i want show that case details in HS2. why i need to show like this because of i can easily compare the duplicate details.

Any body known how to do the above requirement please help it is so important for us. If you have any sample please provide me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you have a list of items that you want to display in the first human service, and then when you select one item and you click on a button you want to display details of that one item on a second human service.

It sounds like your problem does not require two separate human services.
You can use one service with two Coaches. You will link the two coaches in the Diagram using the Button and before you reach the second Coach you will load the details of the selected item.

This has the advantage that you already have all your variables because you remain in the same Heritage Human Service.

Here is a screenshot of a diagram as an example of what you can do:

[image: example diagram]

Another option would be to include the contents of HS2 inside a **dialog control** in the coach of HS1. When the button is clicked the dialog will pop up so you can see the details and on the background you will still be able to see the list of HS1. The diagram would then look like this:

[image: example diagram 2]